# Migrating old posts to new wp, how to extrapolate infos from the post body to custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, migration

I need to migrate some information that are store in the post body (like "price:200$"), extrapolate them somehow and put them into custom fields. how do I do that?

The blog is about restaurants and the location and prices are written in the body of the posts, I need to have them into custom fields so I can perform searches on them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you Loop over all of you posts and use (probably) `preg_match` to extract information.

The long answer is that this could be pretty tricky, depending on how consistent your data entry is. Here is an example:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT ID,post_content FROM {$wpdb->posts}";
$allp = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ($allp as $p) {
  // Deal with price
  $pat = '/price:[0-9]+\$/';
  $price = preg_match($pat,$p->post_content,$matches);
  if (!empty($matches[0])) {
    list($key,$value) = explode(':',$matches[0]);
    update_post_meta($p->ID, $key, $value, $value);
    $new_content = preg_replace($pat,'',$p->post_content);
    //     var_dump($new_content);
  }
  // end of price

  // update content if needed
  if (!empty($new_content)) {
    $post = array(
      'ID' => $p->ID,
      'post_content' => $new_content
    );
    wp_update_post($post);
  }

}
```

That will convert the "price" data you listed above-- price:200$-- and put it into a meta field (`*_postmeta`) under the key "price" with a value of "200$". I'd recommend not including the `$` in the value so you can sort numerically if you ever want to. There are a number o questions here asking how to sort alphanumeric data numerically, and you can't. You need to solve that as the data goes into the database.

You will need a similar regex for each of the bits of information you want to pull out of `post_content`.

**Be very careful.** It is easy to get the regex wrong, and there is no 'undo'. Work on a development server with a copied, and disposable, database until you know you have things right.

### Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: thanks man , looks like the right way to do it.additional question because i'm really new to wp , where do i run this script?

Comment: That will run from pretty much anywhere you put it-- `functions.php` for example. That isn't a good way to do it since it will run every time a page loads. I tested the code in `single.php`. It runs when the page reloads. When I do this kind of thing in the real world, I have a kind of shell plugin with a very simple form allowing me to just click a button on the backend.